# jquery function returns true but cannot process the return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

hi guys here is my code for a function that checks if a certain id is present in my database

```
function checkifuploaded(citenr) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "locationsDB.asmx/checkifexist",
            data: '{"citenr": "' + citenr + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.d) {

                    return true;

                } else {

                    return false;
                }

                //setinfo();
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }

        });
    }
```

now i have a another function which is using the function above

```
function plotnew(lat, lng) {

            $('#latt').val(lat);
            $('#longt').val(lng);
            $("#Panel2").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                height: 350,
                width: 600,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Plot Incident and Save to Database": function () {
                        //$(this).dialog("close");
                        if (checkifuploaded($('#idcr').val())) {
                            $.post(
                                    'insertcrimelocation.aspx',
                                    { lat: $('#latt').val(), long: $('#longt').val(), cirsid: $('#idcr').val() },
                                    function (responseText, textStatus) {
                                        //checkifexist

                                        plot();

                                        $("#Panel2").dialog("close");
                                        $.ambiance({ message: "successfully plotted the incident!",
                                            title: "Success!",
                                            type: "success"
                                        });


                                    })
                                    .error(function () {
                                        $.ambiance({ message: "error on request",
                                            title: "Error!",
                                            type: "error"
                                        });
                                    });
                        } else {
                            $.ambiance({ message: "The C.I.R.S id is not yet uploaded",
                                title: "Error!",
                                type: "error"
                            });
                        }


                    },
                    Cancel: function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });


        }
```

my webservice code below returns as expected it returns true

```
<WebMethod()> _
    Public Function checkifexist(citenr As String) As Boolean
        Dim locs As New crimemsapslocationDataContext
        Dim check = locs.OFFENSEs.Where(Function(offense) offense.CITE_NR = citenr).First
        If Not check Is Nothing Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    End Function
```

what amazes me is that on the second function namely plotnew() if the return value is true it executes the other way around instead of calling a function trough another page is there something wrong with my code?

i got it to work now code below

```
function checkifuploaded(citenr) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "locationsDB.asmx/checkifexist",
            data: '{"citenr": "' + citenr + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.d) {

                    i squeezed my function here to make it work
                    thanks for all the help and info

                } else {

                    return false;
                }

                //setinfo();
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: That's because of the AJAX _Asynchronous_ nature

Comment: welcome to the wonderful world of **Async**

Comment: Ajax can be made synchronous if needed, see $.ajax documentation.

Comment: @Virus that should **always** be a last resort.

Comment: Not if you need your data to keep working.

Comment: Horrible advice.  Never use synchronous xhr.

Comment: i have tried using a callback function but still the same result

Answer (score 0):

You can use a promise object to handle the asynchronous processing. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: i have tried using synchronous and asynchronous request but to no avail